# How to Write a .hyper file (in DataBricks) to Blob Storage (in Azure)?

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have created a .hyper file using
https://github.com/goodwillpunning/hyperleaup.
I want to save the hf file created to an existing azure blob storage instead of publishing it to a tableau server. How do I achieve that using Python(pyspark) in databricks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the `HyperFile` with the `is_dbfs_enabled` parameter set to `True`, and then use the [save](https://github.com/goodwillpunning/hyperleaup/blob/master/hyperleaup/hyper_file.py#L79) function with `path` parameter pointing to the destination on DBFS, but without `dbfs:/` prefix - for example, `/FileStore/`